# Using same form for different scenario in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having a VS solution where there are several projects. For example, one of them is titled 'Management' and another is titled 'Runtime'

If I set Management as default project and run it, an application called Scout opens. If I set Runtime as default project and run it, an application called PM opens.
There is a requirement to use a login form and my requirement is, same login form must be used for both projects and I must create login form under a new project called Data where it is available for use by both the other projects (runtime and management)

My doubt is, while running the program, I need to find out which project is running as default and then load the login form with some dynamically updated controls (for example, if Runtime proj is executed first, the login form should have a label "Welcome to Runtime") and if Management proj is getting executed first, the login form should have a label "Welcome to Management"

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think reusing a `Form` is possible.
First, create your login form like this.
(Maybe you should create it in a DLL in order to reuse it in different projects.)

```
    public partial class LoginForm : Form
{
    //This constructor should only be called by the Designer.
    public LoginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public LoginForm(string title) : this()
    {
        TitleLabel.Text = title;
    }
    public Tuple<string, string> Login()
    {
        if (this.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return new Tuple<string, string>(Username.Text, Password.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            return default(Tuple<string, string>);
        }
    }

    private void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
    }
}
```

Then use it in different scenarios:

```
var details = new LoginForm("Title here").Login();
if (details.Item1 == "username" && details.Item2 == "Password")
{
    //logged in.
}
```

Comment: +1 As in the question, he should create a new project (called `Data` apaprently) which will contain this form. Then both RunTime and Management projects can display the form and set the label / title.

Comment: @Shyc How do I find out which project is being run to display the corresponding login form?

Comment: @HarishKumar You should not try to detect the project running in the login form. Just pass the needed information as arguments in the constructor call.

Comment: @HarishKumar And by writing different code in the `Program.cs` files in different projects, you could pass different information to the `LoginForm`.